# Linux not sleeping and waking properly with Thinkpad X1 Carbon

Tags: suspend, pop-os, thinkpad

I have an X1 Carbon 6th gen and installed the latest version of PopOS on it. I don't have any issues with it other than whenever I close or open the lid, the laptop doesn't sleep immediately and doesn't wake immediately. It works perfectly on Windows but not on any Linux distros I installed (PopOS, Ubuntu, Mint). I mainly want to use PopOS.

Things I've tried:

- Updating the laptop's firmware.
- Changing the sleep state in the BIOS to Linux.
- Disabling Intel Speedstep Technology in BIOS.
- Changing power options from max performance to balanced in BIOS.

I don't think this is a problem with the laptop itself since, but I'm a noob with this type of stuff. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_ThinkPad_X1_Carbon_(Gen_6)). Looks like you could try disabling the memory card reader and bluetooth before suspend. Although this is from the arch wiki, it should still be relevant for other distros.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [link-only answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) are discouraged, as the link may become invalid or the linked content change. Please edit your answer to include at least a summary of the linked explanation.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/434870)